# Why do i get a Segmentation Fault when creating a pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am running a program in C and i am having a segmentation fault. 
After running Valgrind to know a bit mre obout the error i get:

```
==7905== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7905==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4
==7905==    at 0x8049A65: agregar_nuevo_segmento_al_proceso (msp.c:597)
==7905==    by 0x804990E: cargar_segmento_en_estructuras (msp.c:536)
==7905==    by 0x80498B4: CrearSegmento (msp.c:345)
==7905==    by 0x8049313: comunicacionConMSP (msp.c:161)
==7905==    by 0x804924B: escuchar_kernel (msp.c:135)
==7905==    by 0x8049592: conexion_nueva (msp.c:242)
==7905==    by 0x404AD4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==7905==    by 0x4182D3D: clone (clone.S:130)
==7905==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7905==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7905==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7905==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7905==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7905==
```

As you can see, the error starts in the function clone so i look for the error there but i have no idea why it´s happening.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    logger = log_create("Log.txt", "MSP", false, LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    //int resultado = GenerarEStructurasAdministrativas();

    LeerArchivoCfg(argv[1]);
    GenerarEstructurasAdministrativas(cantidad_memoria,cantidad_swap);

    pthread_t th1;
    pthread_t conexiones[BACKLOG];
    int cant_conexiones = 0;
    memoria = malloc(cantidad_memoria);

    //Creo hilo para escuchar la consola de la msp
    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, (void *) consola, NULL );
    log_error(logger, "Se ha creado el hilo para atender la consola de la MSP");

    int yes = 1;
    int sock = 0;
    int newsock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(puerto);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);

    //creo el socket
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        log_error(logger, "Error al abrir el socket");
        close(sock);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        log_error(logger, "Error en setsockopt.");
        close(sock);
        exit(1);

    }
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))
            == -1) {
        log_error(logger, "Error en funcion bind");
        close(sock);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sock, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        log_error(logger, "Error en funcion listen");
        close(sock);
        exit(1);
    }

    //acepto la conexión y creo un nuevo hilo que atienda dicha conexion
    while (1) {
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if ((newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &their_addr, &sin_size))
                == -1) {
            log_error(logger, "Error en accept.");
            continue;
        }
        int p = pthread_create(&conexiones[cant_conexiones], NULL,
                (void *) conexion_nueva, (void *) &newsock);
        cant_conexiones++;
        log_info(logger,p);
    }
    pthread_join(th1, NULL );

    log_destroy(logger);
    free(memoria);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start at the top of the stack trace, not at the bottom. Valgrind says you're (probably) trying to access a NULL pointer in the msp.c file at line 597, start there, figure out which variable is NULL, nest your way backwards. While likely not related, your thread creation has a big race condition, since you pass `&newsock` to the thread, that variable might be re-assigned to a new socket before your thread starts using it.

Comment: this line: while (1) { should be: for( cant_conexiones=0; cant_conexiones<BACKLOG;  cant_conexiones++) {  and remove the line: cant_conexiones++; from the body of the loop.  Otherwise there is no stopping the creation of threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason could be that you are writing memory past the end of the `conexiones` array.  That is, `conexiones` has room for only `BACKLOG` items in it, but your while(1) loop continues incrementing `cant_conexiones` indefinitely until the pointer you pass as pthread_create's first argument is past the end of the array, and then when pthread_create tries to write to it, undefined behavior (and a crash) occurs.

The other reason is that code at line 597 of msp.c (inside the agregar_nuevo_segmento_al_proceso function) is trying to dereference a NULL pointer (with a  4-byte offset).  Since that code isn't posted, I can't say why, but that is what the top of the stack trace is telling you.